# GetUserMedia degrades audio output quality on Bluetooth speakers/phones (Safari)

Tags: macos, audio, safari, bluetooth, getusermedia

Setup:
Safari Version 13.1.1 (15609.2.9.1.2)
Mac OSX Catalina, Version 10.15.5 (19F101)

Steps:

1. Play a song (I use Quicktime)
2. Load Google Meet in Safari and start an instant meeting
3. Safari asks for device permissions (choose any microphone)
4. Upon providing the permission the audio quality of the currently running audio **immediately degrades.**

Is this expected or normal behaviour ? What could be causing this behaviour ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming. Try https://apple.stackexchange.com/